# FOSUserBundle - MultiSelect groups don't work after update

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I updated composer on my symfony project, and i could not continue to use my custom "SecurityRolesType".

Any idea to update it ? following, codes and errors.

Error : Notice: Array to string conversion 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Here a stack screen capture http://s11.postimg.org/j6nlup4ar/screencapture_stack.jpg

Here a capture of rendered HTML http://s17.postimg.org/l6mmskmof/Screen_Shot_2015_09_28_at_10_41_19_PM.png

```
<?php

namespace MYP\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class SecurityRolesType extends ChoiceType
{
    protected $pool;

    /**
     * @param Pool $pool
     */
    public function __construct(Pool $pool)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->pool = $pool;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

        $attr = $view->vars['attr'];

        if (isset($attr['class']) && empty($attr['class'])) {
            $attr['class'] = 'sonata-medium';
        }

        $view->vars['attr'] = $attr;
        $view->vars['read_only_choices'] = $options['read_only_choices'];
        //$view->vars['full_name'] = substr($view->vars['full_name'], 0, -2);

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);

        $roles = array();
        $rolesReadOnly = array();

        $securityContext = $this->pool->getContainer()->get('security.context');

        // get roles from the Admin classes
        foreach ($this->pool->getAdminServiceIds() as $id) {
            try {
                $admin = $this->pool->getInstance($id);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                continue;
            }

            $isMaster = $admin->isGranted('MASTER');
            $securityHandler = $admin->getSecurityHandler();
            // TODO get the base role from the admin or security handler
            $baseRole = $securityHandler->getBaseRole($admin);

            foreach ($admin->getSecurityInformation() as $role => $permissions) {
                $role = sprintf($baseRole, $role);

                if ($isMaster) {
                    // if the user has the MASTER permission, allow to grant access the admin roles to other users
                    $roles[$role] = $role;
                } elseif ($securityContext->isGranted($role)) {
                    // although the user has no MASTER permission, allow the currently logged in user to view the role
                    $rolesReadOnly[$role] = $role;
                }
            }
        }

        // get roles from the service container
        foreach ($this->pool->getContainer()->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles') as $name => $rolesHierarchy) {

            if ($securityContext->isGranted($name)) {
                $roles[$name] = $name . ': ' . implode(', ', $rolesHierarchy);

                foreach ($rolesHierarchy as $role) {
                    if (!isset($roles[$role])) {
                        $roles[$role] = $role;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices' => function (Options $options, $parentChoices) use ($roles) {
                return empty($parentChoices) ? $roles : array();
            },

            'read_only_choices' => function (Options $options) use ($rolesReadOnly) {
                return empty($options['choices']) ? $rolesReadOnly : array();
            },

            'data_class' => null,

            //'expanded' => true
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'myp_security_roles';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the fix you can see commented was working after some cache deletion.

```
$view->vars['full_name'] = substr($view->vars['full_name'], 0, -2);
```